# What games are these Steam Indie Sale characters from?

Tags: game-identification

So I stumbled upon some old screenshots and I found this one:

[image]

I took it long time ago precisely to ask this, but forgot.

SO what games are those characters from?

Some of them are pretty obvious, but I am missing some...

1. Deponia
2. Giana Sisters
3. ???
4. Super Meat Boy
5. ???
6. Castle Crashers
7. ???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Number 3 is the [Private Mels](http://store.steampowered.com/app/204315/) custom skin for [Sherriff Lonestar](http://awesomenauts.wikia.com/wiki/Sheriff_Lonestar) in Awesomenauts.

Number 5 is the [Time Goddess](http://halfminutehero.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Goddess) from Half Minute Hero.

Number 7 is [Tear](http://recettear.wikia.com/wiki/Tear) from Recettear.

Comment: wow that was fast! Would be nice if you add a link to #5 as you did to the other 2. Thanks!

Comment: Note to OP, you can fill in the ??? with the answers from LessPop_MoreFizz.

Comment: @Sebie Huh? That would just make the question nonsensical.

Comment: I agree with Chris, a better alternative would be for the answer to include full (or at least partial) details on all seven.

Comment: Oh, sorry @ChrisHayes . Well maybe then format the answer better like TimS said. Sorry for that comment, ignore it if you can. +1 to you. (Made more sense last night..)

Comment: I miss me some Giana Sisters :)